# The core of a reservation system - finding an unreserved item efficiently

Tags: mysql

This seems like a common question, but I have been web searching and can't find the answers.

I want to reserve something for a number of days (no partial days), so I guess I need a table something like:

```
CREATE TABLE reservations 
    (
     item int, 
     customer int, 
     startDate date, 
     endDate date
    );
```

(Hmm, what's my primary key? item and startDate? Do I even need a PK?)

But my main question is how to find a free item, given a start and end date. What does my `SELECT ...` look like?

For bonus marks, can we assume that all items are identical and that I want to make this as efficient as possible, so that if I want to reserve from Friday I would prefer to find a item which is reserved until Thursday (and, thus is free from Friday).

For double bonus marks, if I need an item for X days, I would like to find an item with a hole in its reservations as close to X days as possible.

I think that the problem is that I am trying to find something which is not there (an existing reservation). All other solutions which I have found seem to have a table of bookable dates with an item Id (with a value of NULL, 0 or -1 to mean "not yet booked"). That seems inefficient to me. And how far into the future would this table extend?

Note: some people are asking about the ratio of reads to writes. Obviously each reservation is made only once, so that's one write (maybe one per day, depending on the implementation) and I would expect multiple reads as users search for an unbooked slot.

Comment: I'm surprised that you haven't commented at all on my answer, as I believe it meets all of your needs with a single query. It doesn't require any extra work either, like keeping track of unreserved time periods. Just curious since I did put some time into it -- is there anything I didn't cover?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT item FROM reservations WHERE 
(endDate BETWEEN start AND end) OR (startDate BETWEEN start AND end) OR (startDate<start AND endDate>end)
```

by @Strawberry suggestions a better query will look like this

```
SELECT item FROM reservations WHERE
start<endDate AND end>startDate
```

This will give You items taken on days You are looking for.
Now You need to fin items that are not in this list. so if You have a table with items You could write smth like this

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE item NOT IN 
SELECT item FROM reservations WHERE
start<endDate AND end>startDate)
```

and You get items that are free on period You search for.

start, end are dates You look for startDate, endDate are columns.

```
SELECT item, start-r.startDate as diff FROM items as i 
LEFT JOIN reservations as r USING(item) 
WHERE i.item NOT IN 
(SELECT item FROM reservations WHERE
start<endDate AND end>startDate
) ORDER BY diff
```

have no schema to test it but this query should be an answer for Your 1st bonus

as for 2nd this requires doing some math between rows from one table and no idea comes to my mind now how to do it in pure MySQL if possible.

//edit

I updated queries with one more condition for scenario when existing reservation starts before and ends after searched period.

for 2nd bonus question this should work

```
SELECT item, r1.startDate-r2.endDate as diff FROM reservations as r1 JOIN (SELECT * FROM reservations) as r2 USING (item)
WHERE r1.startDate-r2endDate>=x AND item NOT IN
(SELECT item FROM reservations WHERE
r1.startDate<endDate AND r2.endDate>startDate)
ORDER BY diff ASC
```

but this is going to be very expensive query. May need to add/subtract one day from dates in sub-query.

As You see in all of them I used query from beginning of my post as sub-query and for 1st and 2nd queries this won't be a big issue as it will be executed just once. In last query for 2nd bonus it will have to be executed for each row separately (as there is a join it will be for each item, number of reservations for given item to power of 2) and it may be a bottleneck.

I don't know what are those item You going to reserve but if they are not many <1000 it may be fast enough (it would be up to 365000 rows per year) but if number of items is going to be really big maybe You could make extra condition to look maximum one year in the future and increase this only if necessary plus partitioning it could work pretty fast.

Comment: I wonder if there's a simpler way of expressing this concept?

Comment: this one is simple. I would wonder if there is more complicated way but more optimized, but none is coming to my mind. I'm talking about bonus questions as the first one is best You can get. It is You can improve it slightly by negating a condition instead of putting it in sub-query but You won't get so much of it.

Comment: Hm, maybe take a look at my response from a few days ago... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521175/retrieve-all-records-that-occur-within-specific-date-range-in-mysql/15521635#15521635

Comment: Yeah Your looks a bit better so I was wrong saying that one I have is best one ^^

Comment: I think it does. Could You provide an example when it doesn't?

Comment: The question says that an item returned Thursday will be free on Friday. Your query considers an item returned on Thursday to also be available on Thursday.

Comment: That issue can be fixed by changing the comparison, but the larger issue is that your query has to consider the Cartesian product of reservations for each item. It will get exponentially slower as the number of reservations grows for a specific item. Without indexes, my query ran in 14 seconds; yours took 2m 16 seconds on the same data set. With an index it's still about nine times slower; it took 1.26s where mine took 0.14s.

Comment: Using Strawberry's approach with the correct comparisons, my version is now 20 times faster than this without an index and 2000 times faster with an index.

Comment: I addressed both issues in my post and in comment I wrote that there is probably still place for improvement. I don't have time right now to make test but I believe that if in my solution we add a condition to sub-query (SELECT * FROM reservations) like WHERE r1.startDate>endDate we will have some improvement. In Your solution You look for a space in given period where I search for minimum X days free at any time.

Answer (score 4):

It's not critical to my approach, but I'm going to assume that you have an `items` table. I'll also provide a query that doesn't need an items table. The advantage of a separate items table is that you can easily add or retire items over time. They'll automatically show up in the reservation query results, and you can add criteria later like `WHERE retireDate IS NULL or retireDate > @reservationWindowEnd` to exclude retired items (instead of adding a dummy reservations to achieve the same goal).

As an example,

```
CREATE TABLE items (
    item int, 
    description varchar(255),
    purchaseDate date,
    retireDate date
);
```

Let's also set up some example values for the reservation window we want to match.

```
mysql> set @newReservationStart='2013-06-01';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @newReservationEnd='2013-06-04';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Now let's find a list of items that *are* reserved during at least part of the target duration:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT item
FROM reservations
WHERE
    @newReservationStart BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
    OR startDate BETWEEN @newReservationStart and @newReservationEnd
```

We want the list of items that *aren't* reversed, so we find a list of items not in this list:

```
SELECT
    item
FROM
    items
WHERE
    item NOT IN (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT item
        FROM reservations
        WHERE
            @newReservationStart BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
            OR startDate BETWEEN @newReservationStart and @newReservationEnd
    )
```

Note that if you didn't have a separate items table, you could replace `SELECT item FROM items` with `SELECT DISTINCT item FROM reservations`.

Now that we have a list of items known to be available, let's decide which one we want.

For each item, we'll need to know which of its reservations is the last to end before the target window:

```
SELECT item, MAX(endDate) AS endDate
FROM reservations
WHERE endDate < @newReservationStart
GROUP BY item
```

And we'll want to know which of its reservations is the first to start after the target reservation period:

```
SELECT item, MIN(startDate) AS startDate
FROM reservations
WHERE @newReservationEnd < startDate
GROUP BY item
```

Before going further, let's put it together to get all of this information at once for the relevant items:

```
SELECT
    items.item AS item,
    priorReservation.endDate AS priorEnd,
    nextReservation.startDate AS nextStart
FROM
    items
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT item, MAX(endDate) AS endDate
            FROM reservations
            WHERE endDate < @newReservationStart
            GROUP BY item
        ) priorReservation ON priorReservation.item = items.item
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT item, MIN(startDate) AS startDate
            FROM reservations
            WHERE @newReservationEnd < startDate
            GROUP BY item
        ) nextReservation ON nextReservation.item = items.item
WHERE
    items.item NOT IN (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT item
        FROM reservations
        WHERE
            @newReservationStart BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
            OR startDate BETWEEN @newReservationStart and @newReservationEnd
    )
```

Not too shabby. We also know when the previous reservation ended and when the next one begins. If there is no prior or next reservation, the LEFT JOINs ensure that the corresponding value will be null. Since we know that all of the listed items are available, we can sort however we want to meet the criteria.

We can order by the most "snug" window:

```
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(nextStart, priorEnd)
```

Or minimize the time between the previous reservation's end and this reservation's start:

```
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(@newReservationStart, priorEnd)
```

Or prefer new items, which have never been reserved:

```
ORDER BY ISNULL(priorEnd) DESC
```

Or we could combine multiple options, to favor new items, then select the items which are returned closest to the reservation window's start date, and then prefer the one whose availability best meets the target window:

```
ORDER BY
    ISNULL(priorEnd) DESC,
    DATEDIFF(nextStart, priorEnd),
    DATEDIFF(nextStart, priorEnd)
```

The `LIMIT` keyword can even be used to select only the best fit. Putting it all together,

```
SELECT
    items.item AS item,
    priorReservation.endDate AS priorEnd,
    nextReservation.startDate AS nextStart
FROM
    items
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT item, MAX(endDate) AS endDate
            FROM reservations
            WHERE endDate < @newReservationStart
            GROUP BY item
        ) priorReservation ON priorReservation.item = items.item
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT item, MIN(startDate) AS startDate
            FROM reservations
            WHERE @newReservationEnd < startDate
            GROUP BY item
        ) nextReservation ON nextReservation.item = items.item
WHERE
    items.item NOT IN (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT item
        FROM reservations
        WHERE
            @newReservationStart BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
            OR startDate BETWEEN @newReservationStart and @newReservationEnd
    )
ORDER BY
    ISNULL(priorEnd) DESC,
    DATEDIFF(nextStart, priorEnd),
    DATEDIFF(nextStart, priorEnd)
LIMIT 1
```

Running the query on a reasonable data set takes a disappointingly long time. Using a sample data set with 155 items with about 30 reservations apiece, it took about 15 seconds, which is way too slow for an interactive application.

MySQL evaluates queries from the "outside in", using the outermost query to filter rows that are passed to the inner queries. So let's put the outermost `WHERE` clause in a "test harness" query and see what `EXPLAIN` reveals.

```
mysql> EXPLAIN
    ->     SELECT
    ->         items.item
    ->     FROM
    ->         items
    ->     WHERE
    ->         items.item NOT IN (
    ->             SELECT
    ->                 DISTINCT item
    ->             FROM reservations
    ->             WHERE
    ->                 @newReservationStart BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
    ->                 OR startDate BETWEEN @newReservationStart and @newReservationEnd
    ->         )
    -> ;
+----+--------------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table        | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                        |
+----+--------------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | items        | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  155 | Using where                  |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | reservations | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 3871 | Using where; Using temporary |
+----+--------------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

That doesn't look good. MySQL is running the subselect ("dependent subquery") for each row in the items table. And each time it runs the inner query, it's looking at every entry in the `reservations` table. (This is disappointing, as the set of distinct items produced by the inner query doesn't actually depend on the value of `item` from the outer query. But it's how MySQL works, and a recent comment from an Oracle DBA gives me the impression that it's not alone in this behavior.)

Depending on the number of total available items, the inner query could end up running many times. On my test of 155 items, most of which have ~30 existing reservations apiece, it took about 0.7 seconds to run this query.

Let's try an index to avoid doing a full tablescan on `reservations` for each available item. Intuitively, we might start by indexing the date columns. We don't care which item we end up with, but we're very interested in looking at the right time period:

```
mysql> CREATE INDEX idx_startDate_endDate_item
    ->     ON reservations (startDate,endDate,item);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Unfortunately this won't help as much as expected. MySQL does quite well with `startDate BETWEEN @newReservationStart and @newReservationEnd`, since it knows that `startDate` can only be within a narrow range of values.
But with `@newReservationStart BETWEEN startDate and endDate`, we're not searching a single column that can be narrowed down to a small range. MySQL will have to find all reservations that started before `@newReservationStart`, and decide which of those end after `@newReservationStart`.

Running the same EXPLAIN statement, we get:

```
+----+--------------------+--------------+-------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table        | type  | possible_keys              | key                        | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                     |
+----+--------------------+--------------+-------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+------+------+-------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | items        | ALL   | NULL                       | NULL                       | NULL    | NULL |  155 | Using where                               |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | reservations | range | idx_startDate_endDate_item | idx_startDate_endDate_item | 4       | NULL | 3572 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary |
+----+--------------------+--------------+-------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+------+------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Despite the index, we've only gone from looking at 3871 rows down to 3572. And we're doing this for each value of `items.item`. If we assumed that most of the reservations will be in the past, we could do a little bit better by indexing (endDate, startDate, item). This would start by looking at items whose endDate is after @newReservationStart, and is likely to be a smaller subset. But it's still not ideal. And we'd need a separate index with `startDate` as the first column, since the other part of the `OR` clause looks for a specific range of start dates.

So what now?

We know that MySQL will run the inner query for each value of `items.item`. So we really only need to look for reservations for the item we're currently examining. That could mean turning the query into a SQL join, but let's give the optimizer another shot.

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE reservations DROP INDEX idx_startDate_endDate_item;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> CREATE INDEX idx_item_startDate
    ->     ON reservations (item, startDate);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Running the EXPLAIN statement yet again, we get

```
+----+--------------------+--------------+----------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table        | type           | possible_keys      | key                | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                              |
+----+--------------------+--------------+----------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | items        | ALL            | NULL               | NULL               | NULL    | NULL |  155 | Using where                        |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | reservations | index_subquery | idx_item_startDate | idx_item_startDate | 5       | func |   38 | Using where; Full scan on NULL key |
+----+--------------------+--------------+----------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------+
```

Not bad at all! Just for fun, we might as well eliminate the "Full scan on NULL key" note by creating `items.item` as `NOT NULL`. And we overlooked the fact that `endDate` is used in the query, but it's not in the index. MySQL will use the index for most of the work. There's no reason to make it consult the full table just to check endDate, so let's replace the index too:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE items MODIFY item INT NOT NULL;
Query OK, 155 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 155  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> ALTER TABLE reservations DROP INDEX idx_item_startDate;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> CREATE INDEX idx_item_startDate_endDate ON reservations (item, startDate, endDate);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

And `EXPLAIN` now gives us:

```
+----+--------------------+--------------+----------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table        | type           | possible_keys              | key                        | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+--------------------+--------------+----------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | items        | ALL            | NULL                       | NULL                       | NULL    | NULL |  155 | Using where              |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | reservations | index_subquery | idx_item_startDate_endDate | idx_item_startDate_endDate | 5       | func |   38 | Using index; Using where |
+----+--------------------+--------------+----------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
```

MySQL is now using the index for all of the information it needs from `reservations`. And the query runs in 0.14 seconds, which seems reasonable for an interactive application.

If you didn't want a separate table for items, you could do something like the following.

```
SELECT
    reservationItems.item AS item,
    priorReservation.endDate AS priorEnd,
    nextReservation.startDate AS nextStart
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT item FROM reservations) AS reservationItems
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT item, MAX(endDate) AS endDate
            FROM reservations
            WHERE endDate < @newReservationStart
            GROUP BY item
        ) priorReservation ON priorReservation.item = reservationItems.item
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT item, MIN(startDate) AS startDate
            FROM reservations
            WHERE @newReservationEnd < startDate
            GROUP BY item
        ) nextReservation ON nextReservation.item = reservationItems.item
WHERE
    reservationItems.item NOT IN (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT item
        FROM reservations
        WHERE
            @newReservationStart BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
            OR startDate BETWEEN @newReservationStart and @newReservationEnd
    )
ORDER BY
    ISNULL(priorEnd) DESC,
    DATEDIFF(nextStart, priorEnd),
    DATEDIFF(nextStart, priorEnd)
LIMIT 1
```

Finally, using [Strawberry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529673/strawberry)'s [answer from a question about matching date ranges in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521175/retrieve-all-records-that-occur-within-specific-date-range-in-mysql/15521635#15521635) cuts the runtime roughly in half over my initial approach. Interestingly the `EXPLAIN` output is exactly the same. But the final query, shown below, now runs in 0.07 seconds.

```
SELECT
    items.item AS item,
    priorReservation.endDate AS priorEnd,
    nextReservation.startDate AS nextStart
FROM
    items
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT item, MAX(endDate) AS endDate
            FROM reservations
            WHERE endDate < @newReservationStart
            GROUP BY item
        ) priorReservation ON priorReservation.item = items.item
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT item, MIN(startDate) AS startDate
            FROM reservations
            WHERE @newReservationEnd < startDate
            GROUP BY item
        ) nextReservation ON nextReservation.item = items.item
WHERE
    items.item NOT IN (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT item
        FROM reservations
        WHERE
            @newReservationStart <= endDate
            AND startDate <= @newReservationEnd
    )
ORDER BY
    ISNULL(priorEnd) DESC,
    DATEDIFF(nextStart, priorEnd),
    DATEDIFF(nextStart, priorEnd)
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: If the EXPLAIN is the same then surely the query is (logically) identical!?!? How does NOT IN compare to NOT EXISTS?

Comment: Not necessarily; it means that statements match in terms of the metrics shown by `EXPLAIN`. The optimizer will discard what it can decide is irrelevant, but MySQL has to do a later pass to look at the ones that the optimizer didn't reject.

Comment: NOT EXISTS doesn't seem to make a difference. I'd hope that MySQL will recognize that even a single match would cause the NOT IN to become false.

Answer (score 1):

This would be pretty easy to do outside of the database - select all reservations in the time period you're willing to consider placing a reservation in, use the result to populate an array where a day is either 1 (filled) or 0 (unfilled) and scan the array for gaps of the desired size. O(n) but there are only 365 days in a year, so not going to be slow.

Comment: And if someone wants to reserve for their birthday for the next 10 years?

Comment: @Mawg Don't pre-maturely optimize. Code it - if it's slow, THEN optimize it.

Comment: +1 a good point, but I *do* worry about how far into the future I shoudl extend my tables. I suppose I can extend them on the fly in the app, if needed, but that seems icky.

Comment: @Mawg If your database structure needs to change, then your programs' installer/upgrader can modify the database just like it modifies the programmer. It's not any bigger of a deal than releasing a new version of a program.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you may not *need* this to be too efficient. That said, here's one approach (depending on what your ratio of reads to writes is):

One way would be to have a table which tracks unbooked blocks of time (during whatever time horizon you're interested in, say from 2000 to 2020). Initially, it will be one block of free time for each item. (I'm going to list this in a readable way; I'll leave the schema up to your imagination.)

```
FREE SLOTS
Item 1: January 1, 2000 - December 31, 2020
Item 2: January 1, 2000 - December 31, 2020

RESERVATIONS
(none)
```

When someone makes a booking, you create a reservation, and split the free slot into two smaller free slots (except if that would make it empty). Watch the locking on your data store during this operation!

```
FREE SLOTS
Item 1: January 1, 2000 - May 4, 2012
Item 1: May 8, 2012 - December 31, 2020
Item 2: January 1, 2000 - December 31, 2020

RESERVATIONS
Item 1: May 5, 2012 - May 7, 2012, Barack Obama
```

When a reservation is removed, you check for free slots immediately before and after. If both exist, you coalesce both free slots and the reservation into one free slot. If only one exists, you expand it to fill the space previously taken by the reservation.

Since you can easily keep the duration of a free slot in the table, you can find slots of a desired duration easily (exactly, greater than a certain amount, within a range, etc.). The cost you pay is the locking needed to ensure consistency when you modify the data store.

Answer (score 1):

If you can spare the cash, [Joe Celko's SQL for Smarties](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123820227) might have what you need.

Answer (score 1):

If lookup efficiency is paramount, you'd be better off using a schema more like...

```
CREATE TABLE items
(
    id          INT             NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name        VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE reservations 
(
    item_id     INT     NOT NULL, 
    customer_id INT     NOT NULL, 
    reserved_on DATE    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (item_id, reserved_on)
);
```

...and adding a separate row for each date that an item is reserved for.

This way, the DB will ensure you can't reserve the same item more than once on the same date, and finding which item IDs are free on, say, `2013-04-18` becomes...

```
SELECT
    i.id
FROM items i
    LEFT JOIN reservations r ON (r.item_id=i.id AND r.reserved_on='2013-04-18')
WHERE item_id IS NULL;
```

...which an `EXPLAIN` shows can be satisfied just using the indices...

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------+------+--------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref             | rows | Extra                                |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------+------+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | i     | index  | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL            |   10 | Using index                          |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | r     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 7       | test.i.id,const |    1 | Using where; Using index; Not exists |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------+------+--------------------------------------+
```

It means a little more work is required when adding/modifying the reservations, but assuming you'll be doing more reads than writes, it's probably not a significant overhead.